# uisearchbar and search based on opened section

Tags: ios, iphone

i have a three section in my table view.each section contains different arrays i need to search a value based on opened section.
array are:
1.Colors
2.Numbers
3.Alaphabet

please help me i am new to iOS...give me solution thanks in advance...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:

            cell.textLabel.text =self.colors[indexPath.row];
                        break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text =self.numbers[indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text =self.alpha[indexPath.row];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIButton *titleButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30);
    [titleButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    titleButton.tag = section;
    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0: sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Colors", @"Colors");
            break;
        case 1: sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Numbers", @"Numbers");
            break;
        case 2: sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Alabaphet", @"Alabaphet");
            break;
        default: sectionName = @"";
            break;
    }
    [titleButton setTitle:sectionName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return titleButton;
}
-(void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender
{

    if(selectedIndex== sender.tag)
    {
        selectedIndex=50;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndex=sender.tag;
    }

    [menuTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: how you open a section?

Comment: Check this out, it explains it in detail http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view

Comment: @Akhilrajtr  i am posted full code...